# HTTP 400 error bad request, what is the cause ? and how can I fix this error?

Tags: python

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))

cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode()

mysock.send(cmd)

while True:

    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if (len(data) < 1):
        break
    print(data.decode())
mysock.close()
```

Comment: if you just want todo get request use the requests modul it makes your life easier (https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

Comment: why do I get error although I type the same with Dr. Charles Severance(guy from YouTube)

Comment: I edit the answer, maybe the guy from youtube use a diffrent platform

Answer (score 0):

Try request modul

```
pip install requests
from requests import request
request("GET", "http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt").text
```

Edit, you have to set correct new lines and carriage return correct **\r\n\r\n**:

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

mysock.connect(("data.pr4e.org", 80))

cmd = "GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n".encode()

mysock.send(cmd)

while True:

    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    print(data.decode())
mysock.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you are trying to send a request using TCP

See [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview#http_flow) to see how it works

HTTP requires `\r` before the new lines, which when I add to the message, works well!

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))

cmd = 'GET /romeo.txt HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: data.pr4e.org\r\n\r\n'.encode()

mysock.send(cmd)

while True:

    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if (len(data) < 1):
        break
    print(data.decode())
mysock.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem, often overlooked, is that the line break in a raw HTTP request needs to be carriage return plus linefeed. So your problem can be overcome thus:

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
cmd = 'GET /romeo.txt HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: data.pr4e.org\r\n\r\n'.encode()

assert mysock.send(cmd) == len(cmd)

try:
    while True:
        data = mysock.recv(4096)
        if len(data) <= 0:
            break
        print(data.decode())
finally:
    mysock.close()
```

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: @KoJohn if this solved your problem please "accept" it using the button on the left.